# Passing a file as a command line argument does not register as a path in CLion

Tags: c, file, null, command-line-arguments, fopen

im trying to pass a file as an argument to my code and I cant get the name of the file to match the file path on CLion. Basically, when I try to open the file for reading, it ends up being null (probably a path error). I tried putting the absolute path into the fopen function and it works just fine. The text file is located in the same folder as the .c file. Any advice on this?

```
char* inputFile = argv[1];
char* outputFile = argv[2];
int start = atoi(argv[3]);
int end = atoi(argv[4]);
char *target = argv[5];
char *replacement = argv[6];

if (start > end || start < 1 || end < 1)
{
    return 1;
}

char line[102];

FILE *input = fopen(inputFile, "r"); # input is NULL
# if you change the variable inputFile to the absolute path of the file instead,
# the program runs just fine

while(fgets(line, 102, input))
{
    printf("x");
}
```

Comment: `fopen` works relative to the current working directory of the program. Is the file there?

Comment: You need to place the file you want to read in the ```cmake-build-debug``` folder, When you create a new project, you should be left with a folder with the project's name. Inside that folder you'll find ```CMakeLists.txt```, ```main.c```, and a folder named ```cmake-build-debug```.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie file is in the same folder as main. not sure why it wasn't working.

Comment: @Ramux05 thank you so much! really helpful. 
Eventually I just ended up using the absolute paths for my files as my arguments.